# Not able to send email with Java code while running remote server

Tags: java, email, exception, networking, smtp

I am trying to send an email using Java while running a remote server. Here is my code:

```
    import java.util.*;
    import javax.mail.*;
    import javax.mail.internet.*;

    //import javax.activation.*;

    public class Email {

    private static String SMPT_HOSTNAME = "smtp.mtnl.net.in";
    private static String USERNAME = "20870134";
    private static String PASSWORD = "2070252342";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Recipient's email ID needs to be mentioned.
    String to = "katha4494@gmail.com";

    // Sender's email ID needs to be mentioned
    String from = "safepassw0rd@gmail.com";

    // Assuming you are sending email from localhost
    // String host = "localhost";

    // Get system properties
    Properties properties = System.getProperties();

    // Setup mail server
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", SMPT_HOSTNAME);

    // Get the default Session object.
    // Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

    // create a session with an Authenticator
    Session session = Session.getInstance(properties, new Authenticator() {
        @Override
        protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication(USERNAME, PASSWORD);
        }
    });

    try {
        // Create a default MimeMessage object.
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

        // Set From: header field of the header.
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

        // Set To: header field of the header.
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(
                to));

        // Set Subject: header field
        message.setSubject("This is the Subject Line!");

        // Now set the actual message
        message.setText("This is actual message");
        System.out.println("Sending message ....");
        // Send message
        Transport.send(message);
        System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
    } catch (MessagingException mex) {
        mex.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
```

I am getting the following error:

```
    Sending message ....
    javax.mail.MessagingException: [EOF]
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1481)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1512)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:1054)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:634)
at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:189)
at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:118)
at SendEmail.Email.main(Email.java:61)
```

I got the server hostname, username and password from my ISP.I am new to Java networking and I cannot understand what is wrong. Please help.

Comment: have you added smtp port ??

Comment: @user3145373ツ how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look on this example :

import java.util.Properties;

```
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class SendMailTLS {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final String username = "username@gmail.com";
        final String password = "password";

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
          new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
            }
          });

        try {

            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("from-email@gmail.com"));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                InternetAddress.parse("to-email@gmail.com"));
            message.setSubject("Testing Subject");
            message.setText("Dear Mail Crawler,"
                + "\n\n No spam to my email, please!");

            Transport.send(message);

            System.out.println("Done");

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

For more details you can [visit](http://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/). Here code is available.

Other [tutorial](http://www.javatpoint.com/example-of-sending-email-using-java-mail-api) with full description.

Still Get problem, post me.

Comment: Thank you, it worked perfectly! Can you tell me what I did wrong?! Are we running a local smtp server here?

Comment: In your code  you are doing so that's why problem occur, in answer it used gmail smtp server for to send mail and that we have to use otherwise we can't send mail. we can also use other smtp server like yahoo, live, etc. but gmail is commonly used. Great that you solved your problem. :)